# Failed to add a string to a file on a remote host

Tags: bash, double-quotes

I've written function to execute any command on a remote host.

```bash
## The ssh connection function
ssh_function(){
    local IP="$1"
    local COMMAND="$2"
    local STATUS

    if [[ $IP == $(hostname -i) ]]
    then
        STATUS=$(${COMMAND} 2>/dev/null)
    else
        STATUS=$(ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" -i $KEY_PATH root@"$IP" ${COMMAND} 2>/dev/null) 
    fi

    echo "$STATUS"
}
```

So if `$IP` is an local IP address the command will be executed on a localhost.

When I try to add these commands in the script:

```bash
ssh_function $CURRENT_NODE_IP "echo 'LimitMEMLOCK=infinity' >> /usr/lib/systemd/system/opensearch.service"

ssh_function $CURRENT_NODE_IP "echo 'MAX_LOCKED_MEMORY=unlimited' >> /usr/lib/systemd/system/opensearch.service"
```

I see in terminal

```bash
'LimitMEMLOCK=infinity' >> /usr/lib/systemd/system/opensearch.service
'MAX_LOCKED_MEMORY=unlimited' >> /usr/lib/systemd/system/opensearch.service
```

So the `ssh_function` prints them in terminal and doesn't add them to the file.

Therefore if the parameter `$2` has `>>` or `''` or `""`, the function works as `echo` operator.

The same situation with command

```bash
ssh_function $CURRENT_NODE_IP "sed -i 's/^-Xms.*/-Xms2g/' /etc/opensearch/jvm.options"
```

But that command

```bash
ssh_function $CURRENT_NODE_IP "apt -qq install opensearch=1.3.12"
```

works perfectly.

I can't understand the logic. Should I screen the `""` symbols in the argument `$2` (`$COMMAND`)?

PS1. After @tjm3772 comment I've edited the function

```bash
ssh_function3(){
    local IP="$1"
    local OPTION="$2"
    local FILE="$3"

    if [[ $IP == $(hostname -i) ]]
    then
        echo $OPTION >> $FILE
    else
        ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" -i $KEY_PATH root@"$IP" echo $OPTION >> $FILE
    fi
}
```

It works, but only for the `>>` operator.

PS2. **The answer**

I just use the `eval` operator in the function

```bash
## The ssh connection function
ssh_function(){
    local IP="$1"
    local COMMAND="$2"

    if [[ $IP == $(hostname -i) ]]
    then
        eval "${COMMAND} 2>/dev/null"
    else
        eval "ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" -i $KEY_PATH root@"$IP" ${COMMAND} 2>/dev/null"
    fi
}
```

Comment: The simple tired old case of "don't store commands in variables."

Comment: If it's not clear from the duplicate link - putting commands in variables is fragile in general, but your specific issue here is that you can't trivially put redirection operators into variables because the parser evaluates redirections before it expands variables. You need to factor the redirection out of the expansion.

Comment: For example: change `STATUS=$(${COMMAND} 2>/dev/null)` to `${COMMAND} 2>/dev/null`, delete `echo "$STATUS"`, and then invoke with `ssh_function $CURRENT_NODE_IP "echo MAX_LOCKED_MEMORY=unlimited" >> /usr/lib/systemd/system/opensearch.service`. This is **still fragile in the general case** but would succeed for the simple example presented here.

Comment: @tjm3772, thank you for your explanation! Unfortunately it doesn't work. The function takes `echo MAX_LOCKED_MEMORY=unlimited` as an argument and doesn't writes anything to the file. I've written a new function in the end of the topic. It works. Is there a good practice method to redirect text to a remote file? I found only the construction `echo "text" | ssh $CURRENT_NODE_IP sed -f /dev/stdin $FILE`.